# Embed a PowerPoint slide in a Microsoft Word document keeping animations

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I am on Office 2016. I am following the following guidelines

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/link-or-embed-a-powerpoint-slide-in-a-word-document-2e421b6d-dd5d-4e3b-a0c7-dc9732d0da01

However, the object does not keep the original animations from the slideshow, which is vital.

How can I solve this issue?

https://i.snipboard.io/mUA3Bq.jpg

Comment: Please see my reply to this same question that you asked in Microsoft Answers.